# How to make function of SQL Queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the the following query and I need to run it many times with different names, But How can I make a function of all the queries so that I only need to run that function instead of all the queries one by one.

```
update clean.vehicles set make='Ford' where type ilike '%explorer%'
update clean.vehicles set make='Chevrolet' where type ilike '%lumina%'
update clean.vehicles set make='Ford' where type ilike '%crown%'
update clean.vehicles set make='Subaru' where type ilike '%suburu%'
update clean.vehicles set make='Subaru' where type ilike '%legacy%'
update clean.vehicles set make='Infiniti' where type ilike '%infinitie%'
update clean.vehicles set make='Ford' where type ilike '%windstar%'
update clean.vehicles set make='Volkswagen' where type ilike '%vw%'
update clean.vehicles set make='Mitsubishi' where type ilike '%mitsubishi%'
update clean.vehicles set make='Infiniti' where type ilike '%infiniti%'
update clean.vehicles set make='Chevrolet' where type ilike '%chev%'
update clean.vehicles set make='Chrysler' where type ilike '%plymouth%'    
update clean.vehicles set make='Chrysler' where type ilike '%plymoth%
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need a mapping table to look up the make when you specify the type (or vice versa).

```
Make       Type
Ford       Explorer 
Chevrolet  Lumina 
Ford       Crown 
Subaru     Legacy
```

Then, when you call your function GetMake(type), it does a query using the Type in the query, returns the Make, and you can then use the results in your query above.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could just do...

```
UPDATE clean.vehicles
SET make = CASE
                WHEN type ilike '%explorer%'
                    THEN 'Ford'
                WHEN type ilike '%lumina%'
                    'Chevrolet'
                ELSE
                    make
           END
```

This will do an update on every record though non-matching records should be unchanged. If you are only updating a subset of the records then you could add a WHERE clause to only match those types.